# Connect Localhost Asp.net mvc controller json to front end

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

EDIT:
i put the html file inside the project and seems that without the localhost part now it works, BUT when i press the button it display me 4 row as aspected , the only problem is that I not understand why it give me this error ( i start to search about right now)

undefined: $undefined
undefined: $undefined
undefined: $undefined
undefined: $undefined

I need to retrive the list of a table from a localhost Asp.net MVC Backend but I don't understand what is wrong in my code.

I have searched the internet with no result. On-line, I found some code that should work, but not in my backend, unfortunately.

I am stuck for 4 days and need help.

**FRONT END:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<ul id = "myList" >

</ ul >

< p > Click the button to append an item to the end of the list.</p>

<button onclick = "myFunction()" > Click Me</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest()


request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:59946/Transactions/Gettami', true)
   request.onload = function() {
        // Begin accessing JSON data here
        var data = JSON.parse(this.response)

  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400)
        {
            data.forEach(movie => {

                var node = document.createElement("LI");
                var textnode = document.createTextNode("ElemntFind");
                node.appendChild(textnode);
                document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);

            })
  }
        else
        {
            console.log('error')
      }
    }

    request.send()
   }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**BACK END**

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult Gettami()
 {

     var orderForBooks = from bk in _db.transactions
                         join ordr in _db.products
                         on bk.product_id equals ordr.Id
                         into a
                         from b in a.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         select new
                         {
                             bk.Id,
                             bk.user_id,
                             bk.product_id,
                             product_name = b.description,
                             bk.amount,
                             bk.currency
                         };

     List<TransactionView> Lista = new List<TransactionView>();

     foreach (var item in orderForBooks)
     {
         TransactionView nuovo = new TransactionView();
         nuovo.Id = item.Id;
         nuovo.user_id = item.Id;
         nuovo.product_id = item.product_id;
         nuovo.product_name = item.product_name;
         nuovo.amount = item.Id;
         nuovo.currency = item.Id;

         Lista.Add(nuovo);
     }



     return Json(Lista, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

I expected a result similar to this: (press the button to try)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

 <ul id = "myList" >

 </ ul >

 < p > Click the button to append an item to the end of the list.</p>

 <button onclick = "myFunction()" > Click Me</button>

 <script>
 function myFunction() {

     var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

 request.open('GET', 'https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films', true)
    request.onload = function() {
         // Begin accessing JSON data here
         var data = JSON.parse(this.response)

   if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400)
         {
             data.forEach(movie => {

                 var node = document.createElement("LI");
                 var textnode = document.createTextNode("ElemntFind");
                 node.appendChild(textnode);
                 document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);

             })
   }
         else
         {
             console.log('error')
       }
     }

     request.send()
    }
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: What you see in result? It throws an error or shows blank page?

Comment: And what happens instead of your expected result? Do you understand how to debug / check for errors in both your JavaScript and .NET code?

Comment: i not see any error, the page just not load any row when i press the button;

in my expected result when i press the button some rows appear(just put the code in a .txt file and rename it in .html to try yourself)

Comment: If the best you can tell us is that it "just not load any row", it indicates a lack of proper investigation...do you understand how to use your browser's Developer Tools to debug your JavaScript code? If not, now would be a very good time to learn

Comment: you have right i not thinked of do that, in the meanwhile i fix the problem putting the html file inside the project